# Can't get vim-ruby to work correctly on Git Bash

Tags: ruby, vim, git-bash

I installed [vim-ruby](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby) on Windows by downloading and running the installation script. I have Git-bash and its own packaged vim.

My problem is that I believe indentation and syntax isn't correct. First of all, right after installation I had a tabstop of 8, a shiftwidth of 8 and noexpandtab. I expected ts=2, sw=2, sts=2 and et.

Also, auto-indentation seems to be simply 'autoindent', when I go to a new line vim simply indents as much as the previous line.

I have checked that the filetype is "ruby", and I have copied the files to the correct directory for Windows (`$HOME/vimfiles/`). I added a line to my `_vimrc` for the tabstops and the like, but I am getting the feeling that I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I looked at this plugin really quickly I don't see anything that sets ts=2 sw=2 and sts=2. Why do you think it should set them?. Also tabstop of 8 and shiftwidth of 8 and noexpandtab are the default for vim.

Comment: Yeah, I also looked for ts= lines, and found only some commented out ones. Well, the important issue is mainly the auto-indent. It should set rules for it, no?

Comment: The commented out lines with ts are called [modelines](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline). It sets the ts for the file when the file is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Do you have

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

(especially `indent`) in your vimrc? Also note that vim own indentation script for ruby may come in your way, be sure the installation path for `vim-ruby` plugin appears before default path.

By the way, what files did you copy and where? You should have `~/vimfiles/indent/ruby.vim` with [this](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/blob/master/indent/ruby.vim) content after installation.

Comment: I hadn't, but I tried it and it didn't work. I also checked whether there is another `ruby.vim` somewhere, and I didn't find any in vim's installation dir. Also, my vim-ruby installation is in the correct place, I do have that file exactly there.